Is there way to run automated playwright test written in javascript in kiwi?
I'm going to use kiwi for tcms and my tests written in javascript playwright framework, Is there way to run playwright test written in javascript in kiwi?
I'm intrested to use kiwi for automation and centralizing all test suites
